# Simple-jndi not seeing my initial context

Tags: java, jndi

I want to write a unit test for testing MyBatis code. Because it's not running in a Tomcat server, and the underlaying database code is expecting it, I need to create a JNDI environment. When it does a lookup of the context, it throws a NamingException.

Failing code:

```
    initCtx = new InitialContext();
    envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");  // Fails with a NamingException
```

Unit test setup (Tried this before setting up a properties file)

```
        @Before
    public void setJndiContext() {

        try {
            DriverAdapterCPDS cpds = new DriverAdapterCPDS();
            cpds.setDriver("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            cpds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:...");
            cpds.setUser("myuserid");
            cpds.setPassword("mypassword");

            SharedPoolDataSource dataSource = new SharedPoolDataSource();
            dataSource.setConnectionPoolDataSource(cpds);
            dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
            dataSource.setMaxWait(50);

            SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
            builder.bind("jdbc/reports_dev", dataSource);
            builder.activate();
        } catch (NamingException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Directory Structure:

```
src/test/resources/simple-jndi/config/jdbc/reports_dev.properties
src/test/resources/jndi.properties
```

In reports_dev.properties

```
type=javax.sql.DataSource
driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//dbs-nprd1-vm-002.cisco.com:1550/LSCDEV.CISCO.COM
user=sc_report_new
password=Temp0rary$
```

Relevent dependencies in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My @Before setup is actually running without throwing an exception. It's when I try to get do the lookup that the failure occurs. If I step into the code with a debugger, I can see it has the resource defined by the explicit bind code above, but not the one defined in the properties file. My goal is to set up a JNDI environment that looks like what the code Tomcat runs provides.

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be

builder.bind("**java:comp/env**/jdbc/reports_dev", dataSource);

Also there is no need for the reports_dev.properties file. This file is only relevant to [Simple-JNDI](https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI). But your code uses Spring's SimpleNamingContextBuilder to establish the JNDI environment.